# Detect two consecutive null values in a column

Tags: python, dataframe, isnull

I want a function that returns a boolean (False or True) if there is two consecutive Null values in a dataframe column.

I tried making a loop that iterates on the entire column and returns True if it finds two null values in a row.

```
def consec_null(df,i):
 j=0
 b=False
 while j<(len(df.index)-1):
  if ((pd.isnull(df.iloc[j,i])) and (pd.isnull(df.iloc[j+1,i]))):
   b=True
  else: 
   j=j+1   
 return b
```

This code keeps on running without showing any results or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`.shift(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def consec_null(df, i):
    col = df[df.columns[i]]
    return (col.isnull() & col.shift(-1).isnull()).any()


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A": [1.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, 5.0], "B": [1.0, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0]})

print(consec_null(df, 0))
print(consec_null(df, 1))
```

Output:

```
False  # because A doesn't have 2 consecutive nulls
True   # because B has 2 consecutive nulls
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop if the condition is satisfied. I think you just forget to add `and b` in your `while` condition.

Try replacing:

```
while j<(len(df.index)-1):
```

By:

```
while b and j<(len(df.index)-1):
```

Comment: Thank you, it stopped the infinite loop, but the function doesn't return valid values.